# Regex get everything after -- if not enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net, comments

I'm programming an Lua language syntax highlighter, so I need to handle comments.
The libary wants an regex that outputs the string that needs to be colored.
It should work like this:

Input:

```
test() --I'm a comment
```

Output:

```
--I'm a comment
```

and also

Input:

```
command .. "--help etc"
```

No output

Comment: I don't think that it's going to be easy. Is the library already highlighting strings like in `command .. "--help etc"` as strings? Because I'm sure you can also have something like `command .. "type '--help etc' for help"` and it's just easier to tell the program that this is a string in the code rather than a comment first, and when this has been highlighted, look for the comments. That said, I don't know Lua in and out, so there might be more problematic cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(testData1, "[^""]--.*")
If m.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
End If
```